# How to solve a linear system when there isn't an exact solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, gaussian-elimination

I've been trying to solve this linear system using Gaussian elimination, but I can't seem to finish it.

$ x +0y - z + w = 0 $

$ 0x + 2y + 2z + 2w = 2 $

$ x + y + 0z + 2w = 1 $

$$ \left[
\begin{array}{cccc|c}
1 & 0 & -1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 1
\end{array}
\right] \Rightarrow \left[
\begin{array}{cccc|c}
1 & 0 & -1 & 1 & 2 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1
\end{array}
\right] $$

$$ \\ -R_1\rightarrow R_3 \\ \frac{1}{2} R_2 \\ $$

And what then? I couldn't come up with a conventional solution where I just start with finding the rightmost variable and all other variables show themselves easily then. $ -R_2 \rightarrow R_3 $ doesn't end up in anything sensible. Could you please give me a hint on how to move on from here?

p.s. First time using the formatting, pardon my mistakes.

Comment: possible typo, in the right hand column of the augmented matrix you have column $2,2,1.$ However, your system with variables says $0,2,1$

Comment: and your third row should be 1,1,2,0,1 to agree with the system

Comment: @WillJagy: Note that the LHS of the third equation has $\cdots+2w+0z$ rather than $\cdots+2z+0w$.

Comment: Apologies, @HenningMakholm is right, it's the variables I named wrong, and there was a typo in the first matrix.

Comment: omn, next, in the augmented matrix, subtract row 2 off of row 3 so that the new row 3 is all zero. This is the final form, and shows that there are infinitely many solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From

$\left[
\begin{array}{cccc|c}
1 & 0 & -1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right]$

add the free variables $z=s$, $w=t$ to get

$\left[
\begin{array}{cccc|c}
1 & 0 & -1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & s\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & t
\end{array}
\right]\to
\left[\begin{array}{cccc|c}
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & s \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1-s \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & s\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & t
\end{array}
\right]\to
\left[\begin{array}{cccc|c}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & s-t \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1-s-t \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & s\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & t
\end{array}
\right]$

obtaining
$$\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x\\y\\z\\w
\end{array}
\right)=
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
0\\1\\0\\0
\end{array}
\right)+
\left(\begin{array}{r}
1\\-1\\1\\0
\end{array}
\right)s+
\left(\begin{array}{r}
-1\\-1\\0\\1
\end{array}
\right)t$$

Answer (score 0):

If you continue the elimination process, you get this reduced row echelon form:
$$\left[
\begin{array}{cccc|c}
1 & 0 & -1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right]$$
Since there are no pivots in the $z$ or $w$ columns, this means you can choose $z$ and $w$ freely when constructing a solution. The remaining equations, e.g.
$$ y + 1z+1w = 1 $$
will then allow you to find the corresponding values for $x$ and $y$ that satisfy all the equations.

Answer (score 0):

Next you subtract row 2 from row 3 to get a row of all $0$'s.  Thus you have two free variables ($z$ and $w$), whose values are arbitrary; the top two rows tell you what $x$ and $y$ are in terms of $z$ and $w$.